# Parsing FIXML in R

Tags: r, xml, fix-protocol

I've been searching and searching for a way for parse FIXML in R. It seems all results are only for XML formatting, and not FIXML where the data is contained within the tags. Here is an example file that I'd like to parse, it seems the XML, XML2 libraries aren't built for this format.

```
<FIXML v="FIX50SP2" s="20080115">
    <SecDef RptID="3400001" ReqID="1234567" RspTyp="100">
    <Hdr SID="CME" TID="BRKR" SSub="CPAPI " TSub="user" />
    <Instrmt ID="CS" Src="H" ProdCmplx="ENRGY" SecTyp="FUT" MinPxIncr="0.01"
                UOM="Bbl" UOMQty="1000" PxUOM="Bbl" PxUOMQty="1" SettlMeth="C"
                PxQteMeth="STD" ListMeth="0" TmUnit="Mo" Exch="NYMEX" Desc="
                WTI Calendar Swap" />
    <InstrmtExt>
        <Attrb Typ="29" Val="Y" />
        <Attrb Typ="25" Val="1" />
        <Attrb Typ="24" Val="2" />
        <Attrb Typ="24" Val="12" />
    </InstrmtExt>
    </SecDef>
</FIXML>
```

Like I said before, I've tried many solutions from both the XML and XML2 libraries as well as tidy. Nothing seems to pull the data correctly from the FIX format.

From the example above, I'd like the result to be a df like this:

| RptID | ReqID | RspTyp | SID | TID | SSub | TSub | Instrmt ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3400001 | 1234567 | 100 | CME | BRKR | CPAPI | CS |  |

You get the picture. Once it gets down to the , it would be slightly different:

| Attrb Typ="29" | Attrb Typ="25" | Attrb Typ="24" | Attrb Typ="24"|
| Y | 1 | 2 | 12 |

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: From the way you phrase the question, it looks like you haven't worked out that these things like `v="FIX50SP2"` are called attributes, and that every XML library has a way of reading attribute values.

Answer (score 2):

The "xml2" library can easily parse out the attributes and the values.
It just takes a couple of extra steps to move from the list of attributes to the data frames.

```r
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
    
page <- read_xml('<FIXML v="FIX50SP2" s="20080115">
   <SecDef RptID="3400001" ReqID="1234567" RspTyp="100">
      <Hdr SID="CME" TID="BRKR" SSub="CPAPI " TSub="user" />
         <Instrmt ID="CS" Src="H" ProdCmplx="ENRGY" SecTyp="FUT" MinPxIncr="0.01"
         UOM="Bbl" UOMQty="1000" PxUOM="Bbl" PxUOMQty="1" SettlMeth="C"
         PxQteMeth="STD" ListMeth="0" TmUnit="Mo" Exch="NYMEX" Desc="WTI Calendar Swap"/>
            <InstrmtExt>
            <Attrb Typ="29" Val="Y" />
            <Attrb Typ="25" Val="1" />
            <Attrb Typ="24" Val="2" />
            <Attrb Typ="24" Val="12" />
            </InstrmtExt>
            </SecDef>
            </FIXML>')


 SecDef <- page %>% xml_find_all(".//SecDef") %>% xml_attrs() %>% bind_rows()
 Hdr <- page %>% xml_find_all(".//Hdr") %>% xml_attrs() %>% bind_rows()
 Instrmt <- page %>% xml_find_all(".//Instrmt") %>% xml_attrs() %>% bind_rows()
 Attrb <- page %>% xml_find_all(".//Attrb") %>% xml_attrs() %>% bind_rows()
```